# Check for container type

Tags: c++, list, vector, typeid, typeinfo

How can I check for a type of container? I.e.

```
template <class Container1>
void func (Container1 &cont_1)
{
  if (cont_1 is list container)
    //do stuff
  if (cont_1 is vector container)    
    //do other stuff
}
```

The only two possibilities I have are list and vector. Note that I don't know the type of values within `list`/`vector`, i.e. `vector<char>` or `vector<int>`, etc. is possible, thus I just want to get the information of getting a vector or a list.
I came across `typeid` and `type info`, but did not really get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function overloading to achieve that:

```
template<typename T>
void func(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    //Do something with vector
}

template<typename T>
void func(std::list<T>& list)
{
    //Do something with list
}
```

Or using `typeid`, which is probably less than ideal, because the code in either case would have to be compilable for both `std::vector` and `std::list`, as templates are known at compile time, and even though the branch might not execute on a `std::list`, the compiler doesn't know this at that point, and so it will fail to compile, trying to apply a `std::vector` operation on a `std::list`.

```
template<template<typename, typename> class C, typename T, typename Alloc>
void func(C<T, Alloc>& container)
{
    if (typeid(container).hash_code() == typeid(std::vector<T, Alloc>&).hash_code())
        ; //Do something with vector
    else if (typeid(container).hash_code() == typeid(std::list<T, Alloc>&).hash_code())
        ; //Do something with list
}
```

Comment: Is there a way not using overloading? If I have a function that is completely the same, except for this `if`-statement, wouldn't it be nice to not to have everything twice?

Comment: @SemtexB Presumably the stuff in the `if` does something. So put that in overloaded functions.

Comment: @SemtexB you could also extract repeating code into some other function and call it inside both overloads or reverse direction and create `func_if` which would do only the conditional stuff and call it from your original `func`

Comment: Yeah, just realised it after adding the comment. Works great, thanks!

Comment: @SemtexB here's a solution with `typeid` :)

Comment: @W.F. Sorry, I don't understand your comment, can you explain it please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

An approach with overloading is of course better but for the completeness there is another one using sfinae mechanism. Before c++11 exemplary code would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <bool V, class T = void>
struct enable_if { };

template <class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
   typedef T type;
};

struct true_type {
   static const bool value = true;
};

struct false_type {
   static const bool value = false;
};

template <class T>
struct is_list: false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_list<typename std::list<T> >: true_type { };

template <class T>
struct is_vector: false_type { };

template <class T>
struct is_vector<typename std::vector<T> >: true_type { };

template <class C>
typename enable_if<is_vector<C>::value>::type func(C &c) {
   // c is a vector here
   std::cout << "This is a vector" << std::endl;
}

template <class C>
typename enable_if<is_list<C>::value>::type func(C &c) {
   // c is a list here
   std::cout << "This is a list" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v;
   func(v);
   std::list<int> l;
   func(l);
}
```

In c++11 it would get a little bit simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct is_list: std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_list<typename std::list<T>>: std::true_type { };

template <class T>
struct is_vector: std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct is_vector<typename std::vector<T>>: std::true_type { };

template <class C>
typename std::enable_if<is_vector<C>::value>::type func(C &c) {
   // c is a vector here
   std::cout << "This is a vector" << std::endl;
}

template <class C>
typename std::enable_if<is_list<C>::value>::type func(C &c) {
   // c is a list here
   std::cout << "This is a list" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v;
   func(v);
   std::list<int> l;
   func(l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write some tests utilizing variadic templates:

```
#include <vector>

// is_vector
// =========

namespace Detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct is_vector_type : std::false_type
    {};

    template<typename ... Types>
    struct is_vector_type<std::vector<Types...>>  : std::true_type
    {};
}

template<typename T>
struct is_vector_type : Detail::is_vector_type<typename std::decay<T>::type>
{};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_vector(T&&) {
    return is_vector_type<T>();
}

// Test
// ====

#include <iostream>

template <class Container>
void func (Container &container)
{
  if (is_vector_type<Container>()) {
    std::cout << "vector\n";
  }
  // or
  if (is_vector(container)) {
    std::cout << "vector\n";
  }
  // ...
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    func(v);
    static_assert(is_vector(v), "");
}
```

Comment: This way using e.g. `cont_1[i]` in conditional section of vector he will cause compilation error...